# Google Analytics Cross Domain Measurment issue with hyperlinks containing #

Tags: google-analytics

I am seeing some issues with Google Analytics and the way it inserts the GA id into cross domain measurement links. I can reproduce this both with Google Tag Manager and then also the old school way by just loading the GA script directly. Code here:

```
<html>
<script>
  (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
  i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
  }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
  })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-111111111-1', 'test.com');
  ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
  // Load the cross-domain linker plugin.
  ga('require', 'linker');
  // Define which domains to autoLink.
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['test-domain.net']);
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<body>
  <a href='http://test-domain.net/#/test-domain/site.html&clicker=true'>Click me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I would expect the output of the url to be:

`http://test-domain.net/#/test-domain/site.html?clicker=true&_ga=2.115223111.1566745105.1588030631-1078940747.1588030631`

However the result of this is actually

`http://test-domain.net/&_ga=2.115223111.1566745105.1588030631-1078940747.1588030631#/test-domain/site.html?clicker=true`

Simply removing the hash in the href and the link looks like this.

`http://test-domain.net/test-domain/site.html?clicker=true&_ga=2.81275223.1566745105.1588030631-1078940747.1588030631`

This is easy to replicate in a JSFiddle as seen here. https://jsfiddle.net/andrewmacnaughton/xa3yp876/1/

I do realize that what I have below is possibly an antiquated version of using GA Cross Domain, however i receive exactly the same via GTM. 
Does anyone have any ideas here. We are stalled on putting this into production as we are convinced that 1: The URL is ugly, 2 and most importantly: Not convinced that GA will track things correctly as it looks like an invalid URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this if anyone ends up here.
Instead of allowing Google to auto append the GA code to the link, i had to manually decorate it.

```
<body>
  <a id='test' href='http://test-domain.net/test-sss/#/site.html?click=true'>Click me</a>
  <script>
    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
      i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
      }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-111111111-1', 'auto');
    ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
    // Load the cross-domain linker plugin.
    ga('require', 'linker');
    // Define which domains to autoLink.
    // Adds click handler that decorates `destinationLink`.
    var destinationLink = document.getElementById('test')
    destinationLink.addEventListener('click', function () {
      ga(function (tracker) {
        var linkerParam = tracker.get('linkerParam');
        var uri = buildUrl(destinationLink.getAttribute('href'), linkerParam)
        destinationLink.setAttribute('href',uri)
      });
    });
    function buildUrl(baseURL,linkerParam){
      return baseURL.indexOf('?')>-1 ? baseURL + '&' + linkerParam : baseURL + '?' + linkerParam      
    }
  </script>
</body>
```